# How to visualize a ByteArrayOutputStream as PDF on Android?

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I am creating an application that will generate a PDF on Android (with `itextg` library) without storing it, just to show the info as a PDF.

I have the following code to generate the PDF:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
document.open();
document.add(new Paragraph("Hello world"));   
document.close();

byte[] pdfByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
```

and it works fine but I could not find a working example that work for me (using a `ByteArrayOutputStream`). These are the questions that I have looked:

- [Need help to convert a Pdf page into Bitmap in Android Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814758/need-help-to-convert-a-pdf-page-into-bitmap-in-android-java/16294833#16294833)
- [How to render PDF in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883355/how-to-render-pdf-in-android/)
- [How to read a pdf in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831019/how-to-read-a-pdf-in-android)
- [PDF to byte array and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131116/pdf-to-byte-array-and-vice-versa)
- [PDF text extraction using iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821107/pdf-text-extraction-using-itext)

but with any of their responses I have been able to show the PDF on Android.

How can I visualize the PDF that I have generated in my Android application?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have to start activity that renders PDF format: `intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");` and create your own `ContentProvider` that serves your generated PDF

Comment: Didn't you ask that question already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788794/is-there-some-way-to-visualize-data-as-pdf-without-storing-it-on-android

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I do not think so because as BrunoLowagie points out, it was off-topic because I was looking for a general purpose. Now it is more specific, with code and some related questions (in the other question I did not know what should I search). Should I delete the other question and maintain this one as it is better asked?

Comment: @pskink Now I am looking about it because I never have used it. I will put an answer if I get it or edit the question with more code when I complete it if I am not able to get it.

Comment: and? does custom `ContentProvider` work?

Comment: @pskink I tried doing with `ContentProvider` but I was not able to get it. I am looking more examples to have a reference.

Comment: examples will not help here, you need to find out the solution by yourself

Comment: @pskink Yes, that's true. I am reading documentation about it but I think that an example always help to visualize how it works better (just a simple example, not to copy-paste an internet example) P.S: I am not asking about to get it here.

Comment: see `ContentProvider#openFile(Uri uri, String mode)`